# Question about conclusion of proof of theorem 6.20 in Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The theorem is as follows.

> **6.20 Theorem** Let $f \in \Re$ on $[a,b]$. For $  a \leq x \leq b$, put
>
> $$F(x)  = \int_a^x f(t)dt$$ Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$; furthermore, if
> $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$  of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is
> differentiable at $x_o$ and $$F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$$
>
> (I have omitted the proof of continuity of $F$ on $[a,b]$)
>
> Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Given $\epsilon > 0 $ choose
> $\delta > 0$ such that
>
> $$\vert f(t)- f(x_o) \vert < \epsilon $$
>
> if $\vert t- x_0 \vert < \delta$, and  $a \leq t \leq b $. Hence, if
>
> $x_0 - \delta < s \leq x_0 \leq t < x_0 + \delta$ $\enspace$ with:
> $a\ \leq s < t \leq b$
>
> we have by theorem 6.12(d)
>
> $$\left| \frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t-s} - f(x_0) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{t-s} \int_s^t [f(u) - f(x_0)]du \right| < \epsilon$$
>
> it follows that $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$

I imagine I'm missing something obvious, but why does the last line allow us to conclude that $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$? In my mind I want to see that
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow s} \frac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s} = f(x_0),
$$
but what I understand from the last statement is that the fraction $\frac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s}$ and $f(x_0)$ become arbitrarily close, but I don't see why we can claim that the limit is attained. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First fix $s=x_0$ and conclude that the right hand derivative of $F$ at $x_0$ exists and equals $f(x_0)$. Then take $t=x_0$ and show that the left hand derivative of $F$ at $x_0$ exists and equals $f(x_0)$. That proves that $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is it enough to say that because the final inequality holds for elements in the intervals $x_0-\delta < s \leq x_0 \leq t < x_0+\delta$, if we take any $t$ such that $x_0-\delta < t< s=x_0$ then we have that $\lim_{t \rightarrow s^-} \frac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s} = f(x_0)$, then for any t such that $x_0< t< x_0+\delta$ we have $\lim_{t \rightarrow s^+} \frac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s} = f(x_0)$? I guess I don't understand why fixing $s=x_0$ corresponds to the right hand derivative and not the left one?

Comment: We are letting $t$ tend to $x_0$ through values **greater** than $x_0$. So we get the right hand derivative when we fix $s$ to be $x_0$.  @AndreyYanyuk

Comment: Ah perfect thanks!